# Is there any way to use Google Protobuf on pypy?

Tags: python, c++, protocol-buffers

Protobuf with pure python performance 3x slowly on pypy than CPython do.
So I try to use c++ implementation for pypy.

These are two error (PyFloatObject undefined and const char* to char*) when I compile protobuf(2.6.1 release) c++ implementation for pypy.

I compile successfully after I modify python/google/protobuf/pyext/message.c,But I get 'Segmentation fault' error finally when I use protobuf with c++ implementation on pypy.

I don't know how to fix it, help me please!

Answer (score 1):

So this is a happy non-answer using my experience. The pure-python bindings for google protobuf are a terrible port of C/C++ stuff. However, I had quite a bit of success wrapping C google protobuf generated bindings using cffi. Someone should go ahead and create a more generic binding, but that would just a short consulting stint.